Get defined version espressif library
Trying to get lower version of espressif8266 library for my Platformio Espressif project by defining version number:
platform = espressif8266@2.7.1
Got error:
Resolving d1 dependencies...
Platform Manager: Installing espressif8266 @ 2.7.1
UnknownPackageError: Could not find the package with 'espressif8266 @ 2.7.1' requirements for your system 'windows_amd64'

How to fix that?
Whole section content in platformio.ini :
[env:d1]
platform = espressif8266@2.7.1
board = d1
framework = arduino

monitor_speed = 9600

build_flags =
;  -DDEBUG_ESP_SSL
;  -DDEBUG_ESP_TLS_MEM
  -DDEBUG_ESP_PORT=Serial
;  -DDEBUG_ESP_CORE
;  -DDEBUG_ESP_WIFI
;  -DDEBUG_ESP_OTA

lib_deps =
  # Using a library name
  WifiManager
  ArduinoJson
  PubSubClient 
  ;RemoteDebug
upload_port = COM3

